# How to add 2 tables with multiple table columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables with same field sponsor. I am trying to get data from both the tables. 
When i try to get data from single column it works properly for example:

```
$q1 = "
SELECT username 
  FROM member_master 
 WHERE sponsor = 'user1' 
 UNION 
SELECT fname 
  FROM upgrade_master 
 WHERE sponsor = 'user1'
";
```

But when i add more columns in query it gives error mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\

This is my code:

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$q1 = "SELECT username FROM member_master WHERE sponsor='user1' UNION SELECT fname, lname FROM upgrade_master WHERE sponsor='user1'";
$e1 = mysqli_query($connection, $q1);
if(mysqli_num_rows($e1)>0)
{   
    echo '<table><tr>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($e1))
    {
    $username = $row['username'];
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];
    echo '<td>'. $username . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $fname . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $lname . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Do not try your query in PHP until you make it run in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a JOIN instead of a UNION for this. Try this statement:

```
SELECT mm.username, um.fname, um.lname FROM member_master mm  JOIN upgrade_master um ON mm.sponsor = um.sponsor where mm.sponsor = 'user1';
```

A union is when you want to pull one similar field from two tables and list all the values for that field. That is why it only works with one column.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: No problem :)  glad to help

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` requires both queries to return the same number of columns.
What you can do is concatenate the 2nd query's 2 columns to 1 column:

```
SELECT username 
FROM member_master 
WHERE sponsor='user1' 
UNION 
SELECT concat(fname, ' ', lname) 
FROM upgrade_master 
WHERE sponsor='user1'
```

or add in the 1st query a *dummy* `null` column:

```
SELECT username, null lname 
FROM member_master 
WHERE sponsor='user1' 
UNION 
SELECT fname, lname 
FROM upgrade_master 
WHERE sponsor='user1'
```

Also note that `UNION ALL` is always better for performance, if you don't want want duplicates filtered out which is what `UNION` does.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @JSLearner Are you sure that the answer that you accepted does what you want? Because this is not what you described in the question.

Comment: I got new learning with your post that column should be same for both the tables.

Comment: @JSLearner the answer that you accepted joins the tables but you asked union in your question. These are 2 different things.

Answer (score 0):

you must use INNER JOIN to do like that

```
"SELECT member_master.username, upgrade_master.fname, upgrade_master.lname FROM member_master INNER JOIN upgrade_master ON member_master.sponsor = upgrade_master.sponsor WHERE member_master.sponsor='user1'"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.